# How to set fixed No. of rows display in the group section in rdlc

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have table in member billing.In that 11 days as fixed in billing every time.
Some member not having 11 days record .ie 5days or 10 day or like that.In that I want add blank rows to set 11 days with 11 rows.How to make it rdlc.
see the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiO5u.png)

Comment: One way to do it is to create those "empty" rows in your data source.

Comment: How to add empty rows dynamically in rdlc